# Losing file data calling openFileInput on my service eventually as the service runs on Android

Tags: java, android, service

On my service, I want to check data every few seconds. 
This works for a few minutes, but eventually `subs.txt` becomes an empty file and the previously entered data is lost.

```
while(true) {
    SystemClock.sleep(1000);
    try {
        //looking if needed to update


        FileInputStream fin = openFileInput("subs.txt");
        String objEnc = "";

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin, "UTF-8"));
        StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
        objEnc = input.readLine();
        while (objEnc != null) {
            sbuilder.append(objEnc);
            objEnc = input.readLine();
            if (objEnc != null) {

                // sbuilder.append("\n");

            }
        }
        input.close();
        objEnc=sbuilder.toString();
        fin.close();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        ManySubs obj = gson.fromJson(objEnc, ManySubs.class);
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
```